# GWT Trying to get a View to be resizable in Height

Tags: gwt, render, uibinder

I'm currently Initializing a GWT view i created and i'm setting it's height explicitly.

the view isn't resizable in height.
whenever i render the view (clear from root panel and re-add to root panel),
the view is resizable in height...

```
RootRootPanel.get().clear();
RootPanel.get().add(asWidget());
```

i don't wish to render the view in the init() function.

is there another way to make the view resizable in height?

thanks

Comment: RootRootPanel.get().clear(); Typo?

Comment: If you are looking at resizable, then you should be using RootLayoutPanel and not RootPanel.

Comment: If you set the height of the widget being added to the RootLayoutPanel to 100%, it should fill the RootLayoutPanel vertically at all times.  I am not quite sure what you mean by making "the view resizeable in height".  Is this on an orientation change?  Or is the user changing the size of the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Resizable screens, Use `RootLayoutPanel.get().add()` method. Add the widgets inside to and don't forget to mention its size in percentages through out the hierarchy. I had the simillar problem. Just check the following link and its accepted answer.

[GWT Re-sizing components on browser window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771922/gwt-re-sizing-components-on-browser-window-resize)

Comment: Sorry, it's RootPanel and not RootRoot :)