# How to make GWT panel resizable depending upon the content in the panel?

Tags: gwt

I am working on a piece of code in which I have a panel and say 5 radio buttons listed vertically. Next I change this number to 15 but my panel size is say 100*100 in which last few radio buttons will not get displayed. So now I want my panel to resize automatically depending upon the inner panel size. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. To make your application to work browser's resize, you should start
   working on [LayoutPanels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) first.
2. Then remember you have to set your panels and widgets `width` and `height` attributes in percentages
3. Make sure that the entire hierarchy contains only [LayoutPanels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels)
4. Don't ever use Absolute Panel when working with resizing of the application

If you land up in trouble when working with [LayoutPanels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) like I did, the following link will help you

[GWT Re-sizing components on browser window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771922/gwt-re-sizing-components-on-browser-window-resize)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your experience with screen design and lay-outing.You can search about responsive and adaptive layouting concepts and try it out with GWT.

For a start - you should reference GWT attempt at re-sizable screens using [LayoutPanel](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels)

You can also try using a scroll panel in your case (if 50 buttons appear what then scenario? )