# IE GWT: DockPanel center component 100% height style is ignored

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt, dockpanel

I have as usual a problem with the Internet Explorer and CSS. I'm using with GWT a DockPanel to create a website with a header, a main part and a footer, all VerticalPanels where I add different Composites/Elements during runtime.

```
    RootPanel rootPnl = RootPanel.get("rootContainer");

    final DockPanel dockPanel = new DockPanel();
    dockPanel.setWidth("100%");
    dockPanel.setHeight("100%");

    rootPnl.add(dockPanel);

    final VerticalPanel headerPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    headerPanel.setSpacing(10);
    headerPanel.setStyleName("gwt-HeaderPanel");
    dockPanel.add(headerPanel, DockPanel.NORTH);
    dockPanel.setCellHeight(headerPanel, "100px");

    final VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    mainPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    mainPanel.setStyleName("gwt-MainPanel");
    dockPanel.add(mainPanel, DockPanel.CENTER);

    final VerticalPanel footerPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    dockPanel.add(footerPanel, DockPanel.SOUTH);
    dockPanel.setCellHeight(footerPanel, "150px");
```

As you can see, I added CSS styles. The main panel looks like this:

```
.gwt-MainPanel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #353334;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0px #232323;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0px #232323;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0px #232323;
}
```

So i put the height to 100% of the center cell, this is working with Firefox as intended, but the Internet Explorer is ignoring it completely. How can i make the IE filling the center part of the DockPanel also vertically? I searched for it already and tried for example to add different DOCTYPEs to the html page.

Please have a look [here](http://am.tassta.com/) for the live example.

Thank you

Comment: try specifying specific height for DocoratorPanel instead of 100%..

Comment: @SCK I tried `dockPanel.setHeight(Window.getClientHeight() + "px");`, but it doesn't have another result. If you look into the page with the IE developer tools, you can see that the dockPanel has 100% height, but the MainPanel doesn't fill the center cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting 100% height of the `VerticalPanel` in the middle of the `DockLayout`, but you are not setting also the middle cell height to 100%. Try with:

```
dockPanel.setCellHeight(mainPanel, "100%");
```

Anyway using tables and percentages can lead to subtle problems that often you need to handle on your own. Always ask yourself "100% of what?".

Also, quoting the javadoc from `DockPanel`:

> This widget has limitations in standards mode that did not exist in quirks mode. The child Widgets contained within a DockPanel cannot be sized using percentages. Setting a child widget's height to 100% will NOT cause the child to fill the available height.
>
> If you need to work around these limitations, use DockLayoutPanel instead, but understand that it is not a drop in replacement for this class. It requires standards mode, and is most easily used under a RootLayoutPanel (as opposed to a RootPanel).

Using `<!DOCTYPE html>` sets the page in standard mode, meaning this will not going to work properly, and in quirks mode you have to experiment on your own.

Try also to consider using a `Layout`-based approach, as suggested by the javadoc. Since you are using a single div for the whole page (that `rootContainer`), it should be painless to use. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i use the DockLayoutPanel along with the RootLayoutPanel, then I have the problem, that there is no scroll bar for the whole page. Note that the center has a fixed size. Is it bad coding, if I set the size of the center cell when the window was re-sized? Or is there a better solution for having a fixed footer/header size and the center has a minimum size, but should fill the rest?

Comment: Yes, `RootLayoutPanel` means taking the whole page and keep track of browser resizing events and provide them accordingly down to the DOM, hence no scrollbar at all. I generally avoid to mix and match table-based widget, try to replace `VerticalPanel`s with simpler `FlowPanel`s and a bit of CSS. Sorry for not being more precise but I can't even reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even if i remove the `VerticalPanel` an just add a `Composite` which holds an `AbsolutePanel` the height of the center component is not correct. I'm wondering because the the description of the `DockPanel`is saying: "A panel that lays its child widgets out "docked" at its outer edges, and **allows its last widget to take up the remaining space in its center**. "

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up layout panels and non layout panels. If you are using Layout Panels then don't use vertical panel and absolute panel. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771922/gwt-re-sizing-components-on-browser-window-resize) and its accepted answer for more details.